# Is $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ with $h(x)=f(x,g(x))$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

1)Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ be a function.
Give  a definiton of f is differentiable in a.
 
2)Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be continuously differentiable. Is $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ with $h(x)=f(x,g(x))$ differentiable?

What I have 
1)Let $U \subset\mathbb{R}^2$  be open, $f: U \to R ^ 2$ a function and $a \in  U$
. The function $f$ is called differentiable in $a$ if there is a linear map $M_a: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{||(f (x) - (f (a) + M_a (x-a))||}  {|| (x-a))||} = 0$

2)I don't know how to show that..

Answer (score 1):

Note that $h: x \mapsto (x, g(x)) =: (x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ is a composite function. Note that the function $\psi: x \mapsto (x, g(x))$ is differentiable [$x \mapsto x$ is differentiable and $g$ is differentiable by assumption], so $\psi$ is differentiable by definition. Then $h = f \circ \psi$ is differentiable by chain rule [$f$ is differentiable by assumption].